# What fields are searched in Articles?

Tags: knowledge

What fields are searched in an Article?  I would imagine Title and Summary, but about custom text fields?   And what about PDF files in file field attachments?  The help says "Text content in a File field attachment is searchable.", but what kind of files are searchable, only text files or binary files (like PDF) too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from our SFDC account technologist.

We don't have a good reference document that has all the answers to your questions, so I gathered it from some internal information and then confirmed with some testing.

Yes, custom text fields on Knowledge articles are indexed and therefore searchable.  Attachments in the form of Text and PDF are also indexed, and their contents are also searchable.