# Search and filter articles by the content on a file field

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, sosl

following this question ([What fields are searched in Articles?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56660/what-fields-are-searched-in-articles))

I'm able to filter articles successfully in the Knowledge tab by doing a search with key-words that are inside the content of the files (PDFs in my case).

However, I need to do this programmatically and I've tried these options:

1)

```
String search = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('q');
search = '' + search + '*';
articles = [SELECT Id, Title, Document__Body__s, 
        Document__Name__s 
        FROM Vet_Portal_POC__kav 
        WHERE PublishStatus = 'online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND Document__Body__s LIKE :search];
```

No luck with this one since Document__Body__s is not filterable!

2)

```
String search = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('q');
articles = new List<Vet_Portal_POC__kav>();
articles2 = new List<Vet_Portal_POC__kav>();
contents = new List<String>();
for(Vet_Portal_POC__kav a : [SELECT Id, Title, Document__Body__s, 
    Document__Name__s 
    FROM Vet_Portal_POC__kav 
    WHERE PublishStatus = 'online' AND Language = 'en_US']) {

    String content = a.Document__Body__s.toString();
    contents.add(content);

    if(content.contains(search)) {
        articles.add(a);
    }
    articles2.add(a);
}
```

I get an error trying to cast the Blob into a String, so no way to search this way either.

3)

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :search RETURNING Vet_Portal_POC__kav (Id, Title, Document__Body__s, 
        Document__Name__s WHERE PublishStatus = 'online' AND Language = 'en_US')];
    articles = (List<Vet_Portal_POC__kav>) searchList[0];
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't search inside the content of the file field.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I also tried this (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/search-conent-of-a-text-file-in-apex) and got the same error in case 2

Comment: `15:16:57.123 (123652818)|USER_DEBUG|[41]|DEBUG|Class.vetKnowledgePOC.<init>: line 31, column 1
15:16:57.123 (123657535)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[41]|System.debug(ANY)
15:16:57.123 (123667396)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[42]|System.StringException.getMessage()
15:16:57.123 (123684113)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[42]|System.StringException.getMessage()
15:16:57.123 (123690900)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[42]|System.debug(ANY)
15:16:57.123 (123695583)|USER_DEBUG|[42]|DEBUG|BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string`